# Is it a good idea to register listeners in my data object or should I use an event bus?

Tags: java, gwt

What I mean by data object is the following:

I'm having a class `CarDescription` that basically wraps and manages a `CarDescriptionDTO` object. `CarDescription` basically functions as a DAO that has access to a `StoreServlet` in order to maintain the respective DTO, keeps it up-to-date and may save it on the server.

What I am having is e.g. a list of cars where I can click on one car and start an Edit-Dialog in order to change its data. I don't like the idea of passing the edited car object (here `CarDescription`) back down to the parent view that initialized the Edit-Dialog. I could just let the presenter of the Edit-Dialog to it:

```
// PLEASE NOTE: This is happening in EditCarDescriptionDialogPresenter
// and NOT in AvailableCarsPresenter which is the parent presenter.

@Override
public void onSaveButtonClicked(CarDescription carDescription) {

    carDescription.save(new Callback<CarDescription >() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CarDescription result) {
            // Here I'm either notifying the parent(s) AvailableCarsPresenter or 
            // I'm doing just what EditCarDescriptionDialogPresenter does
            // and nothing else depending if I have listeners or not.
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) { }
    });
}
```

in `CarDescription` I'd do the actual asynchronous call:

```
public void save(final Callback<CarDescription> callback) {

    new XsrfRequest<StoreServletAsync, CarDescriptionDTO>(this.storeService) {

        @Override
        public void onCall(AsyncCallback<CarDescriptionDTO> asyncCallback) {
            storeService.saveMealDescription(carDescriptionDto, asyncCallback);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(CarDescriptionDTO result) {

            carDescriptionDto = result;
            // Just passing back the managing object:
            callback.onSuccess(CarDescription.this);

            // This is where I could also do something like this:
            /*
            for(CarDescriptionListener listener : carDescriptionListenerList) {
                listener.onDataChanged(CarDescription.this);
            }
            */
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
            // Only the calling object gets notified.
            // Notifying listeners would be pointless.
            callback.onFailure(caught);
        }

    };
}
```

The reason why I think that this could be useful is that different view could be interested in the change of data.

The main disadvantage imho is that every class that is interested in such an event has to implement the listener interface which might or might not be a pain in ones gluteus maximus.

Another option would be an event bus here I guess and I know from some talks that it is recommended to use it in GWT projects - but I'm not sure if I should make use of it in this particular case.

So, how did **you** solve a similar problem and what can you recommend me here?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use an `EventBus`. `Presenters` can then listen to the specific event (i.e `CarSavedEvent`) and handle it appropriately.